# My new App dosent show up in search, and on the app profile page it wont show the "go to app" button

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-wall

My new App dosent show up in search, and on the app profile page it wont show the "go to app" button

i did create the app on a https (secure) canvas page, but it just wont work properly, also my app is coded to post to the users wall, but it's not posting to walls. Can facebook have removed my app wall posting rights? can it have to do with that i use a new app i setup before you had to verify your facebook accounts to create apps? i havent verifyed my account. Can that be it? please i really need your help!

Answer (score 2):

You say it's a new app, so it likely hasn't been submitted to search because you either don't have 10 active users yet, or Facebook hasn't rebuilt their index to include your app yet.

> "We have removed the “Submit to Search" link from the app settings
>   page. Now, when your app reaches 10 monthly active users it will be
>   queued to be indexed the next time we rebuild our index (we rebuild
>   every 2-4 weeks). If you already have 10 monthly active users it will
>   be added to the indexing queue immediately."

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/565/